# Stencyl wont extract? Ubuntu 12.10 64-bits

Tags: extract, gzip

So, I'm on Ubuntu 12.10 64-bits, and I'm trying to get Stencyl to work. I have *Stencyl-2.1.0.tar.gz*, but when I try to extract it (like it says to do in the Stencyl download instructions) it gives me an error that looks like this:

```
An error occurred while extracting files.

truncated gzip input
```

And then the window closes.

I've tried a number of fixes but nothing seems to be working. I'm sure I'm doing something incredibly stupid, as I'm very new to Linux, but I'm having trouble with this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a different way to install Stencyl.

To install Stencyl, just download the .deb file.  You can pick either the [32bit(i386)](https://launchpad.net/~upubuntu-com/+archive/games/+build/3522974) version or the [64bit(Amd64)](https://launchpad.net/~upubuntu-com/+archive/games/+build/3522973) version.

Once downloaded, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to the folder where the file was downloaded and run the command below:

```
sudo dpkg -i <package_name>
```

When the installation is done, type stencyl in dash, and click on the icon as shown in the image below.

[image]